# Check similarity of 2 pandas dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compare 2 pandas dataframes in terms of column names and datatypes. With assert_frame_equal, I get an error since shapes are different. Is there a way to ignore it, as I could not find it in the documentation.

With df1_dict == df2_dict, it just says whether its similar or not, I am trying to print if there are any differences in terms of feature names or datatypes.

```
df1_dict = dict(df1.dtypes)
df2_dict = dict(df2.dtypes)

# df1_dict = {'A': np.dtype('O'), 'B': np.dtype('O'), 'C': np.dtype('O')}
# df2_dict = {'A': np.dtype('int64'), 'B': np.dtype('O'), 'C': np.dtype('O')}

print(set(df1_dict) - set(df2_dict))
print(f'''Are two datsets similar: {df1_dict == df2_dict}''')
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, df2)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data

Comment: df1: 'A': dtype('O'), 'B': dtype('O'), 'C': dtype('O'); df2:  'A': dtype('int64'), 'B': dtype('O'), 'C': dtype('O'). In df1 & df2, 'A' has different datatypes, so I would like to get it highlighted when I run the function. I dont want to compare their row counts.

Comment: **I would like to get it highlighted when I run the function** What do you mean highlight? Do you want `df1.style`?

Comment: @QuangHoang:Sorry, I meant print the differences (if there is a datatype mismatch in columns or additional columns)

Comment: How would you like the differences to be printed? Is it something like the format of `diff` or `git diff`?

Comment: @BillHuang: Just print the differences in the console when I run the function. Like "additional columns" or "datatype differences"

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that if the two dataframe descriptions are outer joined, you would have all the information you want.

example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': list('abc')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1.0,2.0,3.0], 'b': list('abc'), 'c': [10,20,30]})

diff = df1.dtypes.rename('df1').reset_index().merge(
    df2.dtypes.rename('df2').reset_index(), how='outer'
)

def check(x):
  if pd.isnull(x.df1):
    return 'df1-missing'
  if pd.isnull(x.df2):
    return 'df2-missing'
  if x.df1 != x.df2:
    return 'type-mismatch'
  return 'ok'

diff['diff_status'] = diff.apply(check, axis=1)
# diff prints:
  index     df1      df2    diff_status
0     a   int64  float64  type-mismatch
1     b  object   object             ok
2     c     NaN    int64    df1-missing
```